# list screen window number bash

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I was wondering if there is a way to get which window number of screen that is active?
As in: `screen -X get-window-number`
I have found no way to list screen windows to output, only the actual screens.

The reason I would like to do this is because I use screen quite a lot and it would be nice to always see the screen number I'm currently at. I planned to incorporate that into the bash PS1 so it would come to look something like: `[16:00:00][0]admin@Server:/etc$` so it would be [time][window number]username@hostname:pwd$

Does anyone have a way of doing that?

Comment: Have you considered enabling the status line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$WINDOW` variable which is set to the window number of a `screen` window at creation time.
It's as easy as

```
echo $WINDOW
```